# Scraping XML files using R: xpathSApply

Tags: xml, r

I am learning R to scrape large XML (up to 100mb), so definitely not a pro yet. The XML files follow a very strict format: each node is a deal which involves sellers (one or more), buyers (one or more), and type of stocks being transferred (one or more). Each of these have one or more details (names, address, etc.) Here is an anonymized snippet:

```
    <deals>
   <deal>
      <sellers>
         <seller>
            <name>Dave</name>
            <address>Street name</address>
            <city>New York, NY</city>
         </seller>
      </sellers>
      <buyers>
         <buyer>
            <name>John</name>
            <city>Denver, CO</city>
            <phone>123456789</phone>
         </buyer>
         <buyer>
            <name>Pete</name>
            <address>Avenue name</address>
            <city>Kansas, MI</city>
         </buyer>
      </buyers>
      <stocks>
         <stock>
            <id>GOOGL</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>MSFT</id>
            <id>0000789019</id>
         </stock>
      </stocks>
   </deal>

   <deal>
      <sellers>
         <seller>
            <name>Linda</name>
            <city>Philadelphia, PA</city>
            <phone>876-543-210</phone>
         </seller>
         <seller>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <address>Road name</address>
         </seller>
      </sellers>
      <buyers>
         <buyer>
            <name>Monica</name>
            <address>Alley name</address>
            <city>Pensacola, CA</city>
         </buyer>
      </buyers>
      <stocks>
         <stock>
            <id>INTC</id>
            <id>0000050863</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>DELL</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>HPQ</id>
            <id>0000047217</id>
         </stock>
      </stocks>
   </deal>
</deals>
```

When trying to scrape the data, the problem is in the 'one or more'. For now, i simply want to create a data frame that contains a deal number (a sequence number) and the seller information and use the following code:

```
xmldata <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("snippet.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE))
seller_name <- xpathSApply(xmldata, "//deal/sellers/seller/name", xmlValue)
seller_address <- xpathSApply(xmldata, "//deal/sellers/seller/address", xmlValue)
seller_city <- xpathSApply(xmldata, "//deal/sellers/seller/city", xmlValue)
seller_phone <- xpathSApply(xmldata, "//deal/sellers/seller/phone", xmlValue)
```

Unfortunately this does not work for two reasons. First, i cannot identify which seller belongs to which deal. Second, as many details are optional (address, city, phone number), the vectors vary in length and i cannot tell to whom belong the street name or phone number:

```
> seller_name
[1] "Dave"  "Linda" "Anne" 
> seller_address
[1] "Street name" "Road name"  
> seller_phone
[1] "876-543-210"
```

I tried looping through the individual deals using a for-loop, but it is simply too slow. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Thank everyone for all the great solutions! 
I'll try to implement the suggestions below and keep you updated.

Comment: First, sorry for the slow update and thanks for all your help. Unfortunately it turned out R is too slow for large XML files. 

Eventually i went for an alternative solution: reading the XML files as one big string into Python and splitting the string on deals. For each deal, i selected the sellers, buyers, and stocks (by splitting the substring). Then i split these substrings again (for each individual seller, buyer, and stock) and did a regular expression match to get the name, address, etc.
Yes, you read it correctly: this is a large bunch of for-loops, but still faster than R...

Answer (score 2):

Create a function `Value` which gives the `xmlValue` of `node[[name]]` except that if the result would have been NULL then it returns NA.  Using that create a function `getRow` which retrieves one row of data.  Finally apply `getRow` to the XML input as shown.

```
Value <- function(node, name) c(xmlValue(node[[name]]), NA)[1]
getRow <- function(node) sapply(c("name", "address", "city", "phone"), Value, node = node)

t(xpathSApply(xmldata, "//deal/sellers/seller", getRow))
```

giving:

```
     name    address       city               phone        
[1,] "Dave"  "Street name" "New York, NY"     NA           
[2,] "Linda" NA            "Philadelphia, PA" "876-543-210"
[3,] "Anne"  "Road name"   NA                 NA
```

**Note:**  For future reproducibility, the input file `snippet.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deals>
   <deal>
      <sellers>
         <seller>
            <name>Dave</name>
            <address>Street name</address>
            <city>New York, NY</city>
         </seller>
      </sellers>
      <buyers>
         <buyer>
            <name>John</name>
            <city>Denver, CO</city>
            <phone>123456789</phone>
         </buyer>
         <buyer>
            <name>Pete</name>
            <address>Avenue name</address>
            <city>Kansas, MI</city>
         </buyer>
      </buyers>
      <stocks>
         <stock>
            <id>GOOGL</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>MSFT</id>
            <id>0000789019</id>
         </stock>
      </stocks>
   </deal>

   <deal>
      <sellers>
         <seller>
            <name>Linda</name>
            <city>Philadelphia, PA</city>
            <phone>876-543-210</phone>
         </seller>
         <seller>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <address>Road name</address>
         </seller>
      </sellers>
      <buyers>
         <buyer>
            <name>Monica</name>
            <address>Alley name</address>
            <city>Pensacola, CA</city>
         </buyer>
      </buyers>
      <stocks>
         <stock>
            <id>INTC</id>
            <id>0000050863</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>DELL</id>
         </stock>
         <stock>
            <id>HPQ</id>
            <id>0000047217</id>
         </stock>
      </stocks>
   </deal>
</deals>
```

Comment: How would you go about, if you'd like to also include sub values, e.g., if <phone></phone> had a sub grouping of <home></home> and <mobile></mobile>. Would you have to parse the data twice, i.e., once for "//deal/sellers/seller" and another time "//deal/sellers/seller/phone" and merge the two results, or is there a straight forward way to do this in one?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. binding rows with differing numbers of columns --> try `dplyr`'s `rbind.fill()`
2. loosing information when extracting seller information --> chunk your xml into deals and than loop or lapply through these nodeset chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my strategy is to use `xmlEventParse()` to iterate through the file, keeping track of a unique identifier to indicate different states (e.g., 'deal', 'buyer', 'seller') and of the names, addresses, etc associated with that identifier.

I'd use an `environment()` to accumulate information.

```
uid <- 0L
key <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
name <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
address <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
```

`xmlEventParse()` allows callbacks for processing nodes. The callbacks are provided as named lists of functions, with the names corresponding to the xml entities that trigger the callback. So to get going I might have list of 'handlers' that are triggered when entities are observed. The handlers just increment the unique identifier and record the corresponding state

```
handlers=list(deal=function(...) {
    uid <<- uid + 1L
    key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "deal"
}, buyer=function(...) {
    uid <<- uid + 1L
    key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "buyer"
}, seller=function(...) {
    uid <<- uid + 1L
    key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "seller"
})
```

'branches' are like handlers except that they receive the xml node for further computation. These are used to extract leaf-level information

```
branches=list(name=function(node) {
    name[[as.character(uid)]] <- xmlValue(node)
}, address=function(node) {
    address[[as.character(uid)]] <- xmlValue(node)
})
```

It's also useful to have some functions, which I'll call 'final', for processing the collected data, specifically coercing each environment into a data.frame

```
final=list(key=function() {
    k <- as.list(key)
    data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), value=as.character(k))
}, name=function() {
    k <- as.list(name)
    data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), name=as.character(k),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}, address=function() {
    k <- as.list(address)
    data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), address=as.character(k),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
```

I put all of this together into a 'factory' that I can use to create independent instances to parse my file

```
events_factory <- function() {
    uid <- 0L
    key <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    name <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    address <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())

    list(handlers=list(deal=function(...) {
             uid <<- uid + 1L
             key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "deal"
         }, buyer=function(...) {
             uid <<- uid + 1L
             key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "buyer"
         }, seller=function(...) {
             uid <<- uid + 1L
             key[[as.character(uid)]] <- "seller"
         }),

         branches=list(name=function(node) {
             name[[as.character(uid)]] <- xmlValue(node)
         }, address=function(node) {
             address[[as.character(uid)]] <- xmlValue(node)
         }),

         final=list(key=function() {
             k <- as.list(key)
             data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), value=as.character(k))
         }, name=function() {
             k <- as.list(name)
             data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), name=as.character(k),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
         }, address=function() {
             k <- as.list(address)
             data.frame(uid=as.integer(names(k)), address=as.character(k),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
         }))
}
```

And in use the code looks like

```
library(XML)
fname <- "~/Downloads/snippet.xml"
e <- events_factory()
invisible(xmlEventParse(fname, e$handlers, branches=e$branches))
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x=TRUE),
       lapply(e$final, do.call, list()))
```

Resulting in

```
> Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x=TRUE),
+        lapply(e$final, do.call, list()))
  uid  value   name     address
1   1   deal   <NA>        <NA>
2   2 seller   Dave Street name
3   3  buyer   John        <NA>
4   4  buyer   Pete Avenue name
5   5   deal   <NA>        <NA>
6   6 seller  Linda        <NA>
7   7 seller   Anne   Road name
8   8  buyer Monica  Alley name
```

There is a lot of repetition in the code, so probably clever ways to make it more compact.